# Scale a lon/lat vector to a certain length in meter

Tags: r, vector, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have some GPS measured lines with 3 points each that are crooked because of uncertainties of the measurement and that I want to replace by lines with a length of exactly *50m* centered on the center point of the measured lines and with the general direction of the measured points.

To do this, I want to go *25m* from the center point (given by lon/ lat coordinates) into a certain direction, which is given by a lon/ lat vector. Now the problem is, that at different latitudes *25m* are not the same in degrees. I did some calculation to get the length in degrees that 1m is at the location:

```
# Calculate the length of a 1 degree difference
earth_circumference <- 40075016.7
for(i in 1:nrow(coords)){
  coords$d_m_lon[i] <- earth_circumference/360*cos(abs(coords$c_lat[1])*pi/180)
  coords$d_m_lat[i] <- earth_circumference/360
}

# Claculate the difference in degree that 1m at the surface makes
coords$m_d_lon <- 1/coords$d_m_lon
coords$m_d_lat <- 1/coords$d_m_lat
```

I have a *dataframe* (*coords*) which contains in each row the coordinates of the start *s*, center *c* and end *e* point of a line. I did a regression to get the line that approximates the points' general direction best (here, I used *[1]* for the first row of the data; if it works it will obviously be looped to repeat the process for all the lines):

```
# Calculate average transect directions
points <- data.frame(
  x = c(coords$s_lon[1], coords$c_lon[1], coords$e_lon[1]),
  y = c(coords$s_lat[1], coords$c_lat[1], coords$e_lat[1])
)
mod <- lm(points$y ~ points$x)
a <- coefficients(mod)[1]
b <- coefficients(mod)[2]
```

Now I tried to go in the direction given by the model and scale the vector by whatever it takes to make it *25m* long at the given latitude, but somehow the new *start* and *end* points are not on the regression line anymore:

```
center <- c(coords$c_lon[1], coords$c_lat[1])
direction <- c(b-a, 1)/sqrt((b-a)^2 + 1)

start <- center + 25*c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*direction
end <- center - 25*c(coords$m_d_lon[1], coords$m_d_lat[1])*direction
```

Does someone see where the error comes in or know how to resolve the problem? I guess I didn't scale the vector properly...

In case you want the first line of the data to test this:

```
coords <- structure(list(s_lat = -29.6032, s_lon = 29.3376, c_lat = -29.6032, 
    c_lon = 29.3379, e_lat = -29.6032, e_lon = 29.3381, d_m_lon = 96788.6617220582, 
    d_m_lat = 111319.490833333, m_d_lon = 1.03317886848321e-05, 
    m_d_lat = 8.98315283796251e-06), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Take a look at `geosphere`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/ package it will save You a lot of trigonometry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure i what format you want the output, but this might get you started...

results in two new columns; `new_s` and `new_e`, in lon,lat - format..

```
library( tidyverse )  
library( geosphere )

coords <- coords %>%
  #calculate bearing from center ppint to s-point
  mutate( bearing_c_to_s = pmap( list ( a = c_lon,
                                        b = c_lat,
                                        x = s_lon,
                                        y = s_lat ),
                                 ~ geosphere::bearing( c(..1, ..2), c(..3, ..4) ) 
                                 )
          ) %>%
  #calculate bearing from center ppint to s-point
  mutate( bearing_c_to_e = pmap( list ( a = c_lon,
                                        b = c_lat,
                                        x = e_lon,
                                        y = e_lat ),
                                 ~ geosphere::bearing( c(..1, ..2), c(..3, ..4) )  
                                 )
          ) %>%
  #calculate new point s coordinates, 25 meters from c using bearing c_to_s
  mutate( new_s = pmap( list ( a = c_lon,
                               b = c_lat,
                               x = bearing_c_to_s,
                               y = 25 ),
                        ~ geosphere::destPoint( c(..1, ..2), ..3, ..4 ) 
                        )
          ) %>%
  #calculate new point e coordinates, 25 meters from c using bearing c_to_e
  mutate( new_e = pmap( list ( a = c_lon,
                               b = c_lat,
                               x = bearing_c_to_e,
                               y = 25 ),
                        ~ geosphere::destPoint( c(..1, ..2), ..3, ..4 ) 
                        )
  )
```

**output on a map**

```
library( sf )
library( data.table )
setDT(coords)
coords_old <- data.table::melt(coords, measure.vars = patterns( lat = "^[a-z]_lat", lon = "^[a-z]_lon" ) )[, c("lon","lat")]
coords_old <- sf::st_as_sf( coords_old, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326 )
coords[, c("new_s_lon", "new_s_lat") := ( as.list( unlist( new_s ) ) ) ]
coords[, c("new_e_lon", "new_e_lat") := ( as.list( unlist( new_e ) ) ) ]
coords_new <- data.table::melt(coords, measure.vars = patterns( lat = "^(c|new_[se])_lat", lon = "^(c|new_[se])_lon" ) )[, c("lon","lat")]
coords_new <- sf::st_as_sf( coords_new, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326 )

library( leaflet )
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers( data = coords_old, color = "red" ) %>%
  addCircleMarkers( data = coords_new, color = "blue" )
```

old points are red, new points are blue.. center point stays the same....

[image]

Comment: updated.. some small errors removend (I was recycling old code...)

Comment: updated again.... was calculating bearings the wrong way... now it works correct... will add sample output shortly..

Comment: added map of output.